# Sandbox and running /usr/bin/purge using system()

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, sandbox

In an app that is on the Mac App Store, I was doing the following:

```
system("/usr/bin/nice -n 20 /usr/bin/purge &> /dev/null &");
```

This worked fine, but now I'm trying to submit a new version, and they're forcing me to enable the Sandbox. However, with the sandbox, that call fails, giving messages like this in the Console:

```
7/20/13 12:58:59.000 AM kernel[0]: Sandbox: sh(28537) deny file-read-data /dev/ttys000
7/20/13 12:58:59.968 AM purge[28538]: bootstrap_look_up(): Permission denied
7/20/13 12:59:00.000 AM kernel[0]: Sandbox: purge(28538) deny mach-lookup com.apple.appleprofilepolicyd
7/20/13 12:59:00.521 AM purge[28538]: <CPDevice.m:3813> Unable to create new counter client.
7/20/13 12:59:00.523 AM purge[28538]: <CPOSX.m:1188>    Unable to get user client so as to poke the kernel.
7/20/13 12:59:00.000 AM kernel[0]: Sandbox: purge(28538) deny iokit-open ApplePerformanceCounterManagerUserClient
7/20/13 12:59:00.000 AM kernel[0]: Sandbox: purge(28538) deny iokit-open AppleProfileUtilitiesUserClient
7/20/13 12:59:00.000 AM kernel[0]: AppleProfileUtilitiesUserClient: bad busy count (0,-1)
7/20/13 12:59:00.000 AM kernel[0]: Backtrace 0xffffff802d22d4d2 0xffffff802d231fc9 0xffffff802ceb3137 0 0 0 0
```

Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

The official word on NSTask and Sandboxing is 'some executables may work.' For me this translates to 'don't count on it'. There are a ton of questions in the currently down Apple Dev Forums about this and `purge` definitely seems to be one that is blacklisted.